# Do not send email when activating a user

Tags: apex, email, user-record

I'm writing some code that should (de-)activate some users based on some criteria. This part was easy, but one of the requirements is also that this user should **NOT** get an email.

So when I create a new user, he/she does not get an email which is good. But after some events, if a deactivated user(`IsActive = false`) becomes active(`IsActive = true`), I do get an email, even though I use `Database.DMLOptions` in both cases.

```
for (User u : usersToUpdate) {
    u.IsActive = true;
}
Database.DMLOptions dmlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlo.OptAllOrNone = true;
dmlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
dmlo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(usersToUpdate, dmlo);
```

For new users I use the same code, except for `Database.update`, which is an insert there(obviously).

But even though I set both `triggerUserEmail` and `triggerAutoResponseEmail` to `false`, an email is still being sent to the email address of this user.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way not to send emails to users when their records get active?

Answer (score 0):

This is standard SFDC functionality. When you create/activate a user the system sends an email. On the other hand when you deactivate a user the system does not send an email. These are system generated emails and we cannot control it with a flag.

The other thing you can try is freeze the user instead of deactivating.